# Rails: Finding models with missing has_one records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If model **User has_one Profile**, is there a simple way to find all users who have no profile without a custom query (eg NOT `User.where('profile_id IS NULL')`) or processing it in the app?

Since the association between User and Profile is already known to Rails I don't want to restate it. I want to keep this DRY. The actual connection between the models is more complex than this simple example (uses keys and class name) and may change in the future.

Comment: A way to query the `User` model's table without building a query that Rails doesn't natively provide? This isn't very clear.

Comment: Whatever custom query you make can be wrapped up into a `scope` for readability purposes.

Comment: `scope :without_profile, where(profile_id: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tadman & @antonk already said, you probably want to use `scope`:

```
scope :without_profile, where(profile_id: nil)
```

EDIT:
To answer @David Mauricio's question: you could use it by calling `User.without_profile`, to return the AR association of all users with a `nil` `:profile_id`.

@DriverDan : then I'm really unsure what you're asking for. Ask another question with more details, and we can try to answer it!

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a reasonable solution to my simple example.

However, I don't consider it the correct solution when the relationship between the two models is more complex, such as using :primary_key. This would require restating the JOIN within the scope which is exactly what I want to avoid.